# tty with shell_exec?

Tags: php, shell-exec

Is it possible to do shell_exec in PHP, which requires a tty?

```
<?php
   $output = shell_exec("read foo; echo $foo");
?>
```

If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Are you trying to read from a tty? Is this still a question you want an answer to?

Comment: @emilyk I don't remember why I needed this.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
<?php

echo shell_exec('read foo; export foo; echo $foo');
```

Note: The var foo will not be available in your shell after the script exit.